# Stingy Linked Structure and nodes?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, linked-list, nodes

I am fairly new to programming and am unfamiliar with certain terminology and references within Java. Although I believe I have effectively utilized google, I find that asking you guys to dumb it down for me will help me more efficiently.

My question is, what specifically are nodes? And what are they used for? Additionally, what are Stingy Linked Structures used for?

Comment: Nodes are the basic units used to build data structures such as linked lists and trees.

Comment: @ user201535, your question is well answered. Please take time to accept the answer, and consider an upvote

Comment: I am unaware as to how one would "upvote" or "accept the answer" :\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A linked structure is a data structure that consists of a bunch of smaller elements (called *cells* or *nodes*) that are linked together to form a larger structure.  This is similar to how molecules are formed - you have a bunch of smaller atoms that are then connected together to form a molecule.  Many important data structures, such as linked lists or binary search trees - are linked structures.

Linked structures are usually contrasted with array-based structures.  Arrays have a fixed size and are "rigid" - you can't efficiently break them into smaller pieces - so typically growing or shrinking an array-based structure takes time.  Linked structures, being made of smaller pieces, can easily be divided up into smaller pieces or built up out of new pieces.  For example, to append an element to an array, you may have to allocate a giant new array, copy over all the old elements, then append the new element.  With a linked list or linked structure, you could just add another piece onto the end, which can be a lot more efficient.  Similarly, if you have a sorted array and need to insert an element, you may have to shuffle down all of the other elements in the array, since there is no way to "splice" something into the array.  If the sorted sequence is stored in a binary search tree, the new element can be added in in the proper place without moving any other elements around, which makes insertions more efficient.

I don't believe there is anything called a "stingy linked list."  I think you mean ***singly***-linked list, which is a linked list in which each cell (piece) stores only one link, usually to the next element in the sequence.  This makes it easy to scan forward in the list from one element to the next, but makes it difficult to back up one position in the list.

Quite honestly, there is no simple way to enumerate all the cases where you'd want to use a linked structure because so many structures are linked structures.  I would suggest picking up a book on fundamental data types (lists, stacks, queues, trees, etc.) to learn more about this.  I just finished teaching a quarter-long programming class dedicated to this topic, and I doubt it's possible to condense into a single SO answer. :-)

Hope this helps!